# Streaming Music from iPad/iPhone/iPod Touch to PC (AirTunes) in .NET

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c, ios

I saw the projects [shairport](http://sourceforge.net/projects/shairport4w/develop) and [shairport4w](https://github.com/albertz/shairport) which stream music from an iDevice (called AirTunes/AirPlay by Apple) to a computer. I wanted to do the same for my media player. Those two projects are in C/C++/Perl and so I can't port them to C#/VB.

Can anyone explain me how the AirTunes protocol works and how do I implement it in .NET?

Comment: Perhaps you can use one of these projects and call it from your app. If you really want full c#, these project are open source, why don't take a look at the sources and try to port the best (or easier) to c#.NET ?

Comment: I'm not sure what is your question then, you want someone to code that for you? Learning to read a new language is not that hard, it doesn't require the level of knowledge required to write (good) code.

Comment: @Programmer that is by far too broad as a question on SO IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is old but may be a good starting point;

[JustPort](http://nanocr.eu/software/justeport/)

First version of [Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) was based on [this](http://nanocr.eu/2008/03/15/rogue-developers/)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

- port the C/C++ code to .NET / C#
- use the C/C++/Perl code/library via `DllImport` or via `Process.Start` from .NET

Comment: @Programmer either learn C/C++ or find someone who can port this code for you